# Websphere error while deploying web service

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, deployment, websphere

im try to install my app with `Deploy web services` checkbox enabled on websphere 8.5.5.6. but it faild with error wsws0038e

```
000062cc SystemErr     R java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified. 
000062cc SystemErr     R    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2013) 
000062cc SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.util.ArchiveUtil.createTempFile(ArchiveUtil.java:289)
000062cc SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.util.ArchiveUtil.createTempDirectory(ArchiveUtil.java:201)
000062cc SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.etools.webservice.deploy.core.ConsoleEARDeploymentModule.setup(ConsoleEARDeploymentModule.java:48)
000062cc SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.etools.webservice.deploy.core.EARDeploymentModule.execute(EARDeploymentModule.java:63)
000062cc SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.etools.webservice.deploy.core.DeployWebService.deploy(DeployWebService.java:156)
000062cc SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.etools.webservice.deploy.core.DeployWebService.execute(DeployWebService.java:102)
000062cc SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.combined.deploy.WSDeployTask.performTask(WSDeployTask.java:237)
000062cc SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:315)
000062cc SystemErr     R    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:809)
```

which file not found? where he was try to find it?
P.S. my app was created on local machine but deployed on remote.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using the console to install the application? If so, I'd suggest having a look at this link: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/ae/trun_app_instwiz.html . It should have all the information you need to deploy an application on WebSphere with the console, and specifically it outlines any of the additional options to deploy applications with Web Services. Also, this link https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/18d10b14-e2c8-4780-bace-9af1fc463cc0/entry/WebSphere_Web_Services_Trace_Specifications?lang=en will walk you through which trace specs to enable on WebSphere which will help you debug the problem if the previous link wasn't helpful. Turning on more trace should give you a better idea of the issue, rather than this fairly generic error message.